# How save implement class in python?

Tags: python, class, serialization

I have instance of the my class. I want to save implementation of class with instance's pickle copy in file. After, I want to use this instance to another computer where there is no implementation of the my class. I don't want to save text of implementation manually.

How can I do this?

Comment: "there is no implementation of the my class"  Why not?  Send the source to the other computer.  How hard can that be?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict instead of a class.

Comment: It's impossible. I need a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy your source code to the "other computer" then the best best is to use native data structures, i.e. `dict` or `list` or `tuples` etc.

Pack what ever you want to pack & store it in these data structures, then simply do this -

```
import pickle

def save_to_disk(data, filename):
    pickle.dump(data, open(filename, 'w'))
    return

def read_from_disk(filename):
    data = pickle.load(open(filename))
    return data
```

I have heard `cPickle` is faster then `pickle`